# Whatever happened to the default value?

Tags: java, default-value

Code:

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

When I run this, instead of printing the default value of int i.e, 0, it cries an error that `The local variable i may not have been initialized`.

How come and if initialization is mandatory, then why do the primitive data types have default values at all? They might as well have garbage values as C++ does.

Comment: I think that the Java designers would have made it mandatory to initialize fields before first use, if they could.  The problem is that the compiler can't tell what order the methods will be called in, since they could be called from anywhere.  It's a bit different for local variables because the local variable can be accessed only within its method.

Answer (score 6):

Default values are used not for a local variables, only [for a fields in a class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

```
public class A {
    int i;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

> [**Default Values**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)
>
> It's not always necessary to assign a value **when a field is declared**. Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, this default will be zero or null, depending on the data type. Relying on such default values, however, is generally considered bad programming style.
>
> The following chart summarizes the default values for the above data types.
>
> Data Type  Default Value (for fields)
>
> ```
>  byte                     0  
>  short                    0  
>  int                      0  
>  long                     0L  
>  float                    0.0f  
>  double                   0.0d  
>  char                     '\u0000'  
>  String (or any object)   null  
>  boolean                  false
> ```
>
> **Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable.** If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

Comment: Well...I should have known that by now, but no. Please suggest the #1 book to read for Java.

Comment: @KW123 Actually, I\m not a `Java` developer - there is the same behavior in `.NET`, and just googled the docs.